# Is there a way I can align the histogram with the function plot in this graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, alignment

Here's a plot I currently have: (using Python)

[image]

The darkorange curve is my function, generated from

```
plt.plot(x,Yt,color = 'darkorange')
```

while the histogram comes from

```
plt.bar(dic.keys(), dic.values(), width=np.abs((rang2-rang1)/N), color='lightcoral')
```

From this graph we can see they are not quite aligned at the bottom (where both of them should  be 0), I'm wondering is there a way I can make them aligned? Thanks!!

Comment: Just double checking, are they really both supposed to be zero?

Comment: @M Z Ahh, good point, I just realized the curve should be really close to 0, but not strictly equal to. Thanks for the comment:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might need to play around with the offset number below

```
offset = 0.01


Yt = [y-offset for y in Yt]

plt.plot(x,Yt,color = 'darkorange')
```

note that if you want to only offset outside the peak range of the function (the spiky part in the middle) you would need a non-constant offset.